# Subset of rational number and perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

In the book principles of mathematical analysis, Walter Rudin defined perfect set E as a closed set with every point of E to be a limit point of E. Then, later in the book there is a theorem stating "Let P be a nonempty perfect set in $R^k$, then P is uncountable".

I'm a bit confused that if we take $P = (Q\cap[0,1])\subset R$ (where Q is rational number and R is real number). We have $\forall p\in P$, the neighborhood of p must contain a non-p rational number that is in P, which makes every point of p a limit point of P. I can therefore conclude that P is a perfect set. However, doesn't this conclusion contradict with the countability part of the theorem? Do I miss something here?

Many thanks to any help here.

Edit: Delete the misleading statement on boundedness (cr. to Noah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every point of $P$ is indeed a limit point of $P$. However, a perfect set must be **closed**, and $P$ is not closed.

In the context of claiming to show that $P$ is perfect, you say

> "In addition, it should be trivial to see P is bounded."

I think this indicates a misreading of the definition: boundedness is irrelevant to perfection. While $P$ is nonempty, bounded, and has no isolated points, it is not closed - and hence not perfect. So the theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: That's right, will edit that right away.

Answer (score 0):

$P$ is not closed, so it is not a perfect set. What is the closure, $\overline{P}$, of $P$?

Comment: Ah that should be [0,1]. Didn't think in that direction. Thank you so much!